# Help with form and function in sentence

Tags: grammar

I am struggling with the following sentence:

> The minister resigned after disclosure of the scandal.

The minister = form NP/function subject
resigned = form VP/function predicate verb
after disclosure of OR after disclosure = form PP/function adverb?
of the scandal form/function?

I have not found anything in the course literature that helps me sort this out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> *The minister resigned after disclosure of the scandal.*

Here is a simplified tree diagram showing the category and function of the main constituents.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Bill, could you share the tool you've used to (auto-)generate this diagram? (if it's publicly accessible)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko It's not actually a tool, but something I invented in Word/Paint.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very impressive invention!

Comment: @Catarina you can use [this syntactic parser](https://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html), but it doesn't offer fancy diagrams like this.

Comment: @Catarina The advantage of tree diagrams like my one is that they show both category (POS) and function. Of course, you have to know what they are before you can draw the tree!

Comment: Thank you so much! It will definitely help! Sorry for the typing error…of course I meant intervention, but the Edit function seems de-activated. Thank you again, your replies were most useful!

Comment: Just one follow-up question: could "disclosure of the scandal" not be a prepositional complement? The distinction between prep complement and NP complement is not clear to me.

Comment: @Catarina "Disclosure" is a noun, so "disclosure of the scandal" must be a noun phrase. The phrase is functioning as complement of the preposition "after".

Comment: @Catarina PPs can be complements of preps. For example, in "I stayed until after lunch", "after lunch" is a PP functioning as complement of the prep "until". But in your example the complement of the prep "after" is the NP "disclosure of the scandal". Is that clear now?

Comment: Thank you, BillJ, you explain it much better than my grammar book!

Comment: OK, so the exercise is getting more and more complicated. Now we are to determine the function (on clause level or phrase level).

Comment: @Catarina The tree diagram gives the function of each phrase. It's the upper label at each node. The lower one is the phrase category. For example, "after disclosure of the scandal" is a PP and its function is modifier.

Comment: One more question as I cannot figure this one out: is "a bed of roses" a PP or a NP?

Comment: @Catarina It's an NP, because it has the noun "bed" as head. "Of roses" is a PP functioning as object of "bed" within the NP.

Comment: Thank you so much, Bill! I don´t understand how this can be so easy for some...!